# How to create a public Test-net?

Tags: blockchain, testnets

I wanted to implement a public testnet on ethereum on python can anyone help me it must be proof of work as consensus method and currently i am learning hashing and how to implement proof of work but can anyone tell me in detail how transactions work full in documentation or in practical form ?

Comment: Why u want your own test net while u can use any one of the public test net

Comment: Ethereum transactions are explained in detail in the Yellow Paper.

Answer (score 1):

-install metamask extension on your browser.

-resister to https://infura.io/dashboard/ethereum and you can select the testnet(ropsten, kovan, rinkeby...) and check the project_id

-faucet free eth to your wallet to test transaction(aucet.rinkeby.io for rinkeby, https://faucet.ropsten.be/ for ropsten, https://enjin.io/software/kovan-faucet for kovan)

```
from web3 import Web3
Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction
web3 = new web3('https://testnet.infura.io/v3/project_id')

//now we try to test network
account1 ='0x3d..'//from address
account2 = '0x2h..'//to address
private_Key_1 = 'privateKey'
privateKey1Buffer = Buffer.from(private_Key_1, 'hex')
//You can check the balance of wallets(from address, to address)
web3.eth.getBalance(account1, (err,bal) => { console.log('account 1 balance :' , web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether'))})
web3.eth.getBalance(account2, (err,bal) => { console.log('account 2 balance :' , web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether'))})
await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err,txCount) => {
      txObject ={
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            to: account2,
            value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei(''+amount, 'ether')),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),
        }
//2 sign transaction with my private key
tx = new Tx(txObject, { chain: 'mainnet' })
tx.sign(privateKey1Buffer)

serializedTransaction =tx.serialize()
raw ='0x'+serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err,txHash) => {
            console.log('txHash : ',txHash)
            if (txHash === undefined) {
                web3.eth.getBalance(account1, (err,bal) => { alert('Your account has ' + web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether') + ', So Please input less than ' + web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether'))})
                handleSuccessFalse();
            }
            else
                handleSuccessTrue();
        })
    })
  //Finally, You can check transaction success through checking the changed balance of wallets.
  web3.eth.getBalance(account1, (err,bal) => { console.log('account 1 balance :' , web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether'))})
  web3.eth.getBalance(account2, (err,bal) => { console.log('account 2 balance :' , web3.utils.fromWei(bal, 'ether'))})
}
```

I would be happy if this could help you.

Thanks.

Comment: no i was looking for creating a full blockchain or you can say hard forking the ethereum Blockchain can you help me in that ?